# White defense against bishop check in b4

Tags: opening, knights, bishops, defense, owens-defence

I'm a low ranking player and always wondering why for example after:

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "8"]

1. e4 b6 2. d4 Bb7 3. Bd3 e6 4. Nf3 Bb4+
```

white often plays Nc3, so why this and not c3 to kick out the bishop ?

Comment: I (~1800-1900) agree with you. I would even call Nc3 a mistake. c3 to gain a tempo looks a much better move to me. And if you look at the Lichess database 79% play c3 in this position, while only 5% play Nc3.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to have a look at the database. Your comment should have been an answer to be marked as correct answer. Beside, how did you edit to add the checkboard ?

Comment: For the checkboard it's ok I saw you add the fen source